# How are passwords securely shared between the client and server?

Tags: security, ssl, encryption, rsa, tls1.2

Usually when a user logs in, the user details are sent to the sever to authenticate the user. How are these credentials protected in the best way during flight?

Main Questions :

1. I understand the passwords are many times hashed, keeping them secure. Also TLS maintains the in-flight security, But is that the only way the transaction details are kept secure or do websites add any of their own layer of security?
2. In our case, we want to send a passcode to the backend, where another API will be called (that uses password grant) of a third party application. We cannot hash the password, we'll need it in the backend. Will TLS be sufficient for securing it in flight?
3. We were also planing to implement and secure the passcode by RSA (public key) on the client side and unlock it on the backend for use. Should we consider RSA?

Comment: As I told you on your other SO question, in your context there's no way to prevent client-side attacks. If the attacker gets access to one of your users' computer, encrypted or not, he will still be able to steal (and use) your passcode. If you really can't trust your users, then reconsider giving them access to this passcode. Maybe your server should expose some sort of API that will use this passcode internally ? "Will TLS be sufficient for securing it in flight?" short answer : yes, don't bother too much, let the browser do it. Long answer : see @Artjom B. one

Comment: Thanks @ShellCode. This does make more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. I understand the passwords are many times hashed, keeping them secure. Also TLS maintains the in-flight security, But is that the only way the transaction details are kept secure or do websites add any of their own layer of security?

There are very few cases where layering more cryptography on top of TLS are beneficial. Your case doesn't seem to fit them. So TLS should be enough. TLS already provides encryption in transit. RSA would do the same. Defense in depth means layering different security mechanisms on top of each other.
You might hash the password on the client side creating an intermediate password, but considering your 2. question, this is not what you can do.

> 2. In our case, we want to send a passcode to the backend, where another API will be called (that uses password grant) of a third party application. We cannot hash the password, we'll need it in the backend. Will TLS be sufficient for securing it in flight?

Yes, but let the client (your server) validate the certificate chain and don't accept protocol downgrades.

> 3. We were also planing to implement and secure the passcode by RSA (public key) on the client side and unlock it on the backend for use. Should we consider RSA?

No, just use TLS 1.2 or higher with a valid server certificate and let the client validate the certificate chain (browser does that automatically for you).

Keep in mind that TLS needs a trust root. Most client side libraries as well as many browser use the trusted root store of the operating system. A certificate chain presented by the server should end in one certificate that is in the trusted root store.
You could use a self-signed certificate, but then the client would need to pin the public key of that self-signed certificate.